# iTextSharp embeded fonts issue when converting to text

Tags: itext

It's obviously very easy to render text from PDF doc using PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage. However when dealing with PDF created with embedded fonts I immediately stumbled into encoding issues.

Is there a generic method that will handle whatever font since i dont have any control on how pdf is created. My task is simple - convert pdf to text.

I've obviously searched for days before posting but could not find answer.

Thank you in advance!
ER

Comment: iText parser classes already do quite a good job decoding text strings in PDFs. In general if iText cannot properly extract text, you should look for OCR solutions. For specific documents there might be alternative approaches but not in general.

Comment: Thank you mkl! Don't mean to question but i think this is possible. Let me clarify what I'm having issues with.

Comment: It is when fonts are embedded the class seems to be having difficult time to decode. I believe it needs a bit more help pointing to fonts in use.

Comment: Please share an example pdf which you think iText extracts inadequately. That way we can talk seriously and not in general claims.